# Perl - Subroutine argument is another subroutine call

Tags: perl, split

I have a subroutine called grepText, which simply greps a text from another variable. I am trying to split the output. Is it possible to pass the output of grepText as an argument to split directly? without putting the value of grepText in a variable first ? grepText returns a string.

What i am trying to do is:

```
$output = (split ":", grepText("findThis", $Alltext))[1];
```

grepText is as follows

```
sub grepText(){
my @text = split "\n", $_[1];
my $output = grep /$_[0]/, @text;
return $output;
}
```

it doesn't work. Error is

```
Too many arguments for main::grepText at a line 115, near "$Alltext)"
```

Comment: Does grepText return a string? What sort of error are you seeing?

Comment: @ChrisS: Any Perl subroutine returns a string if you treat it that way

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't give us anything useful to go on. Exactly what unexpected behaviour are you seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **very much possible to pass the input of a subroutine to any perl function** directly without using a perl variable.

I think the **issue might be with your "grepText" subroutine**. To debug the issue in detail, much more information is required.

I did try your routine and I was able to get the required output:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
sub grepText
{
 return "hello:world"; # returns a test string
}

my $output = (split ":", grepText($textToFind, $Alltext))[1];
print "$output";
```

Output:

```
world
```

Comment: Got the problem .. i was using prototyping, which i shouldn't . !! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is. But as you've written it `grepText` is getting some strange parameters. In

```
(split ":", grepText(/$textToFind/, $Alltext))[1];
```

you're calling `grepText(/$textToFind/, $Alltext)` which is searching for the value of `$textToFind` in the global variable `$_` and, in list context, is inserting either an empty list `()` or a list containing 1 `(1)` into the parameters

So you're calling `grepText($Alltext)` or `grepText(1, $Alltext)` depending on whether `$_` contains the regex pattern in `$textToFind`

I'm pretty certain that's not what you want to do, so some more information would be nice!

However, whatever `grepText` returns will be split on colons `:` and `(split ":", grepText(...))[1]` will give you the second colon-separated field, which seems to be what you're asking

Comment: grepText returns a string, sorry i mistyped the first line of code (edited the original question)... if i have to pass the stringed output of grepText to split .. what would be the change in code ?

Comment: @Muzammil: The change you have made makes it work fine and do exactly what you have asked for. If you need any more help then you must show the code for `grepText`, and describe the string that it returns, as well as the result you want and what you are getting. We can't do much with ***it doesn't work***